# To calculate Bayes estimator for $\theta $ using squared error loss function

Tags: self-study, bayesian, posterior, prior

The life of an electric bulb, X (in hours), follows the  exponential distribution with mean life $ 1/ \theta $  , where $ \theta(>0) $ is an unknown parameter. The prior distribution of $ \theta $ has a gamma distribution ( $ \alpha , \lambda  $) with mean 0.8 and standard deviation **2. The  average live of a random sample of size 5 bulbs is 3.8 hours**. Calculate the Bayes' estimate of theta  using the squared error loss function.

Also explain the significance of the bold part

Now in this question , since I am learning bayes estimation on my own so I do it step by step

Step1 $\ f(x |\theta ) $  =  $ \theta e^{-x\theta} $

And from the given mean and standard deviation , $ \alpha = 0.16 , \lambda = 0.2  $ since in gamma distribution  mean = $ \frac{\alpha }{\lambda }$
And variance  = $ \frac{\alpha }{\lambda^2 }$

Now  $g(\theta ) =  \frac{\alpha^\lambda \theta^{\alpha -1  } e^{- \theta \lambda } } {\gamma(\alpha )}$

Now after this we will find their joint distribution,  but one thing I am unable to understand is that why are the sample size and average life of bulbs given , where shall is use them ??

I dont think I am doing it correct , can anyone please assist here ??

Comment: What is $f(x, \theta)$? If it is the likelihood ($f(x\mid \theta)$) it doesn't correspond to an exponential distribution at all.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: $ f( x | \theta)  $ here gives the distribution of light bulbs which follow exponential distribution

Comment: @pohoua I hope I made it clear now ?

Comment: Your expression for $f$ in Step 1 is not a valid PDF.

Comment: @whuber than is it the distribution of x only $ f(x) $ ?? I am really confused

Comment: Start by looking up the PDF for an exponential distribution with mean of $1/\theta.$

Comment: @Simran As whuber said, $f(x\mid\theta)$ isn't the pdf of an exponential distribution (it doesn't even depend on $x$). I think you may have confuse it with a uniform distribution...

Comment: Ohh , I got it so $ f(x, \theta ) $ will be $ \theta  e^{x\theta } $

Comment: @pohoua  i feel so stupid , I dont understand why I was able to understand  such a thing, thanks

Comment: Well it happens to everybody...be carefull though, you may have forgotten a minus in the exponential density.

Comment: @pohoua corrected , thanks !